# Invoke JUnit 5 test enumeration and/or execute a test from main entry point, especially an AWS Lambda function

Tags: junit5

**WHY**:

Our organization uses JUnit as our test runner, not only for unit tests, but all test phases.  In an effort to accelerate end-to-end testing, especially UI tests, we are exploring ways to increase parallel execution by wrapping our test classes into AWS Lambda functions and invoking them in parallel.

**WHY LAMBDA**:

The JUnit Console Launcher allows configuring multiple threads.  Why not just use that?  Short answer is scalability.  Adding threads only works until you exhaust your available CPU.  To increase beyond that, you need more expensive hardware that if underutilized is a waste of money.  But if we just configure the test as a lambda, we can invoke the tests with massive parallelism and reduce test times from hours to minutes.

**REQUIREMENTS**:

Given a test class with some number of tests
I want to turn it into a lambda function that does one of two things (depending on how it is called):

- If called with no parameters, it should enumerate the test cases and return a JSON object that lists the test details
- If called specifying a specific test to run, it should trigger that test (with all before and after hooks), and return the results

**The Ask**:

- *Part 1* - Java code I can call from my main entry point function that asks JUnit to enumerate all the tests currently visible
- *Part 2* - Java code to tell JUnit to trigger a specific test

Comment: Have you looked at JUnit Platform‘s launcher API?

Comment: I'm trying, but we're a bit lost about where to start.

Comment: 6.4.1 and 6.4.2 in https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api should give you some code to start with.